# Explain Laravel Core Feature in 5.1 , 5.2, 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, laravel-5, laravel-4

I am a beginner starting out in laravel 5.2

could you please explain bellow concepts

Service Providers
Service Container
Contracts
Facades

Comment: It's explained in the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/ , https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/ , https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/

Comment: You can also join laracast.com to learn more !

Answer (score 4):

You can registered core services of laravel using service providers.